# Magento2 backend sales_order_view.xml not able to override template file

Tags: template, magento2.2.3

I want to override the template file for backend Order view

I've checked template path and found that this file is called.

```
vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/view/adminhtml/templates/sales/order/view/info.phtml
```

So to override I did following in my module

**Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
     <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Wishlist"/>
            <module name="Temando_Shipping"/>
     </sequence>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="left">
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::info.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

And I've put info.phtml in the following path
**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/info.phtml**

But still, it's not working, clear cache and all but still not taking above file.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a very silly typo mistake.

In etc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
     <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Wishlist"/>
            <module name="Temando_Shipping"/>
     </sequence>
</config>
```

It should be like following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Hs_Helper" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
                <module name="Temando_Shipping"/>
                <module name="Magento_Wishlist"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've repeated your steps and the override works for me.

Here's what i did:

Added `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml` to an existing module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="left">
            <referenceBlock name="order_info">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::info.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Copied the contents of `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml` into a new template `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/info.phtml`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info $block
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

$order = $block->getOrder();

$orderAdminDate = $block->formatDate(
    $block->getOrderAdminDate($order->getCreatedAt()),
    \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    true
);

$orderStoreDate = $block->formatDate(
    $order->getCreatedAt(),
    \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    true,
    $block->getTimezoneForStore($order->getStore())
);
?>

<!-- I added this bit -->
<h1>OVERRIDE</h1>
<h1>OVERRIDE</h1>
<h1>OVERRIDE</h1>

<section class="admin__page-section order-view-account-information">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order & Account Information')) ?></span>
    </div>
```

Ran the `setup:upgrade` command to clear all caches:

```
$ php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Visited an order details page in the admin:
    http://www.example.test/admin/sales/order/view/order_id/18/key/29acbf64d18925d298b839dae9c432d2090ec92b3b175649bf3a98c69fae6b47/

[image]

It would appear that the problem therefore lies with the Temando extension. I would check to see if the above steps work after disabling the Temando extension.

If so, I would get in contact with Temando.

Comment: Yeah it seems the problem with Temando extension